# How to add a tap function to the individual bars in a bar chart using the charts_flutter package

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, charts, package

I'm using the charts_flutter package to build a bar chart widget in flutter. I'm trying to make each individual bar do something upon a tap on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/327), you can use :

```
selectionModels: [ charts.SelectionModelConfig(changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) { // add action here }
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. What if I want to add unique actions to each bar? using this solution just gives every single bar the same action.

Comment: You may be able to figure out which bar has been tapped by using `model`. See [this answer](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/537#issuecomment-692259030).

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :)